# I don't understan an axiom

Tags: number-theory

Why $-a \leq x \leq a$ can be written as $\left| x\right| \leq a$? $-a  \leq a$ anyway, why I need to write absolute value there ?

Answer (score 2):

The absolute value is necessary to prevent $x$ from being "too negative". If $a = 5$, $x = -6$, then $x < a$ is true, but $|x| < a$ is false.

Also, be careful in assuming that $-a \le a$, unless you have specified that $a \ge 0$.

Comment: But x=> -a. So x can not be too negative...

Comment: Exactly. Your first expression, $-a \le x \le a$ has a bound on how low $x$ can be. But your second one, $x < a$ does not. That's why you need the absolute value bars.